# How to move div.sidebar.main on mobile in Magento2?

Tags: php, magento2

I've got this issue to solve. I need the container **div.sidebar.main** to be inside **products_list_toolbar**, but only on mobile.

I've tried with **catalog_category_view.xml** but I didn't find a way to move it only on mobile.

this is *toolbar.phtml*, I need view.phtml (filters) between amount and sorter.

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyvä Themes - https://hyva.io
 * Copyright © Hyvä Themes 2020-present. All rights reserved.
 * This product is licensed per Magento install
 * See https://hyva.io/license
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Security.IncludeFile.FoundIncludeFile
// phpcs:disable Generic.Files.LineLength.TooLong

/** @var Escaper $escaper */
/** @var Toolbar $block */

$uniqueId = '_' . uniqid();
$additionalOptions = ['page' => 'p'];
?>
<script>
    function initToolbar<?= /** @noEscape */  $uniqueId ?>() {
        return {
            options: <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWidgetOptionsJson($additionalOptions) ?>.productListToolbarForm || {},
            getUrlParams: function () {
                let decode = window.decodeURIComponent,
                    urlPaths = this.options.url.split('?'),
                    urlParams = urlPaths[1] ? urlPaths[1].split('&') : [],
                    params = {},
                    parameters, i;

                for (i = 0; i < urlParams.length; i++) {
                    parameters = urlParams[i].split('=');
                    params[decode(parameters[0])] = parameters[1] !== undefined ?
                        decode(parameters[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) :
                        '';
                }

                return params;
            },
            getCurrentLimit: function () {
                return this.getUrlParams()[this.options.limit] || this.options.limitDefault;
            },
            getCurrentPage: function () {
                return this.getUrlParams()[this.options.page] || 1;
            },
            changeUrl(paramName, paramValue, defaultValue) {
                let urlPaths = this.options.url.split('?'),
                    baseUrl = urlPaths[0],
                    paramData = this.getUrlParams(),
                    currentPage = this.getCurrentPage(),
                    newPage;

                /**
                 * calculates the page on which the first item of the current page will
                 * be with the new limit and sets that number as the new page
                 */
                if (currentPage > 1 && paramName === this.options.limit) {
                    newPage = Math.floor(this.getCurrentLimit() * (currentPage - 1) / paramValue) + 1;

                    if (newPage > 1) {
                        paramData[this.options.page] = newPage;
                    } else {
                        delete paramData[this.options.page];
                    }
                }

                paramData[paramName] = paramValue;

                if (this.options.post) {
                    hyva.postForm({action: baseUrl, data: paramData});
                } else {
                    if (paramValue === defaultValue.toString()) {
                        delete paramData[paramName];
                    }
                    paramData = Object.keys(paramData).length === 0
                        ? ''
                        : '?' + (new URLSearchParams(paramData));
                    location.href = baseUrl + paramData
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div x-data="initToolbar<?= /** @noEscape */ $uniqueId ?>()"
         class="toolbar toolbar-products flex flex-col md:flex-row lg:items-center gap-2">
        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include $block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

       **HERE I NEED THE FILE view.phtml**


        <?php include $block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml') ?>

        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

but I don't know how to call view.phtml in this file. cause view.phtml is from Magento_LayeredNavigation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use xml to differentiate between mobile/desktop view. You'll need to use js to move the sidebar back and forth between views (Use matchMedia in the js)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35500326)